# How to establish fixed USD fees in Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

In Anchor we can get the minimum balance required for an account to exist without paying rent with the function:

```
anchor_lang::prelude::Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(data_length_in_bytes));
```

I am wondering if this rent exempt amount will always corresponds to a fixed amount of USD so it can be used as a conversion rate. For instance the rent for `4355 bytes` is currently `0.03120168 SOL` (about 1 USD). At the time of writing the market value of `1 SOL = 32,05 USD`, but if the value of 1 SOL raises to let's say 100 USD, will the rent exempt fee be reduced to `0,010000138 SOL` to keep the equivalence with a fixed amount of USD? Or I am being naive in this assumption?

Answer (score 3):

The rent cost in Sol was fixed at genesis, so currently it goes up when Sol goes up and down when Sol goes down.

Eventually, it will be flexible, and will adjust up/down depending the price of Sol and the price of hardware that validators must purchase to run Nodes.

Comment: Is there any conversion rate (SOL -> USDC) at the moment that can be used in Rust programs?